# Dynamically add conditions without having to re-deploy every time

Tags: c#

I have small piece of code of windows service written in c# which looks like this:

```
bool status = assign value based on some logic above;

if ( status == "A" || status == "B" )
{
    DoSomething();
}
else
{
    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

The variable status can have values from A to Z. As of now if the value is `A` or `B` , the call `DoSomething()` method. IF tomorrow there comes a requirement where for status `C` also, I have to call this method, I will have to change the code as below:

```
if ( status == "A" || status == "B" || status == "C" )
{
    DoSomething();
}
else
{
    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

So every time there is change in requirement I need to change the if condition, build and deploy it, which is time taking.Is there a way I can configure it dynamically like in config file or any other file, where I can just add the new status and it will dynamically pick. I just need to restart service and not deploy it every time.

This will be very helpful for me.Thanks!

Comment: _"Is there a way I can configure it dynamically like in config file or any other file"_ the answer is in this sentence, I can't understand why it is a question.

Comment: Create a Windows Workflow and deploy it as an artifact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several possibilities for this:

One could be reading the status-values from a file (.xml/.txt/.ini/...) or a database or some other type of storage and then check with the following:

```
List<string> statusList = ReadStatus();
if(statusList.Contains(status))
   DoSomething();
else
  DoSomethingElse();
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you could simply have a txt/json/any type of file where you store your statuses values.

If you need, you could also utilize `FileSystemWatcher` so you get notifications when file changed. That way you don’t need to restart your app when collection of statuses change.

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.8